# Linux sort folders by numerical value

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, grep, numeric

We have a data set from

```
ls -1 /opt/test/kortinfo/
1.0.0
1.0.1
1.0.2
1.1.0
1.10.0            // Error
1.2.0
1.3.0
1.4.0
1.5.0
1.5.1
1.5.2
1.6.0
1.7.0
1.8.0
1.8.1
1.9.0
```

As we can see here the folder `1.10.0` is misplaced since it is larger than `1.9.0`

We tried to pipe it through `sort -g`, `sort -n` and `sort -ng` but neither will correctly display the folders sorted by their number values.

```
ls -1 /opt/test/kortinfo/ | grep -v "siste" | sort -ng
1.0.0
1.0.1
1.0.2
1.1.0
1.10.0            // Still the same error
1.2.0
1.3.0
1.4.0
1.5.0
1.5.1
1.5.2
1.6.0
1.7.0
1.8.0
1.8.1
1.9.0
```

Does anyone know how I can get these sorted correctly by number value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `-v` switch of `ls`:

```
ls -v
```

`man ls` says:

> -v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text

Comment: I feel like such an idiot. Thank you for an easy solution!
 
My solution was: ´| sort -t . -k1,1nr -k 2,2nr -k 3,3nr´

Answer (score 0):

As a reference, one could also solve this problem with padding the version numbers with brace expansion, if applicable.

Here's an example

```
touch 1.{01..10}.{01..05}
```

This will create the versions with appropriate padding of the version representations and simplify your life significantly.

The result:

```
mace-windu:useme [ ~/Desktop/1 ] ls -1
1.01.01
1.01.02
1.01.03
1.01.04
1.01.05
1.02.01
1.02.02
1.02.03
1.02.04
1.02.05
1.03.01
1.03.02
1.03.03
1.03.04
1.03.05
1.04.01
1.04.02
1.04.03
1.04.04
1.04.05
1.05.01
1.05.02
1.05.03
1.05.04
1.05.05
1.06.01
1.06.02
1.06.03
1.06.04
1.06.05
1.07.01
1.07.02
1.07.03
1.07.04
1.07.05
1.08.01
1.08.02
1.08.03
1.08.04
1.08.05
1.09.01
1.09.02
1.09.03
1.09.04
1.09.05
1.10.01
1.10.02
1.10.03
1.10.04
1.10.05
```